# VB6 and SQL - ODBC driver does not support the requested properties

Tags: sql, vb6, odbc, basic

I am developing a program for a school project that is kind of based on the "How to Use SQL Server with VB6 (inc. select & insert)" video on Youtube.

The program looks like this:

[image: Seach Form]

Clicking a radio button enables the textbox adjacent to it and disables the rest (except for the big textbox. Then inside the Search button, the following code is embedded:

```
Dim aConnection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim aRecSet As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
If txtStuNum.Enabled = True Then
    aRecSet.Open "select * from studentTable where studentNumber'" & txtDisplay.Text & "'", aConnection, adOpenKeyset
ElseIf txtName.Enabled = True Then
    aRecSet.Open "select * from studentTable where Name'" & txtDisplay.Text & "'", aConnection, adOpenKeyset
ElseIf txtGrade.Enabled = True Then
    aRecSet.Open "select * from studentTable where Grade'" & txtDisplay.Text & "'", aConnection, adOpenKeyset
ElseIf txtSection.Enabled = True Then
    aRecSet.Open "select * from studentTable where section'" & txtDisplay.Text & "'", aConnection, adOpenKeyset
End If

End Sub
```

And when I press the search button, this pops up:
[image: Error Message]

All responses are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `=` sign, the form is:

`where field = 'string'`

This code is open to SQL Injection attacks, if a textbox contained a `'` character bad things can happen. Use Parameter & Command objects to avoid this, See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675101(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! However it when I add the "=", it still shows the same error. And about the ' , I personally think that it is okay since I don't expect anyone to use that particular character. Any more possible answer to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Try removing `adOpenKeySet` and instead: `aRecSet.Open "select * from studentTable where section ='" & txtDisplay.Text & "'", aConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly`

Comment: The `'` issue should be addressed, its called an SQL Injection flaw and could allow a malicious user to delete data from your database; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: At the very least you can manually prevent this by escaping `'` to 2 x `'`: section ='" & replace$(txtDisplay, "'", "''").Text & "'"`